# Output displays differently on a Specific Android Device

Tags: android, xml

I created a simple button and `recyclerview` on `XML` in android studio.
For some devices i've tried, the button and `recyclerview` show up normally. 
However this device i mentioned is show up differently.
Here's a the picture.

[Recycler View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJDzB.jpg)

[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6fnV.jpg)

It supposed to be normal size and no text being cropped.
Has anyone ever find the solution for these matter?

[EDIT]
Here's the related `XML` code for the button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dine In/Take Away"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spDineIn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:entries="@array/array_dine_in"
                android:prompt="@string/spinner_dine_in" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/etlTableNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etTableNumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:hint="Table Number" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/etlQtyCust"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etQtyCust"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:hint="Customer Total" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/etlCustomerName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etCustomerName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Customer Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNext"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="Save"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/ButtonTextColor"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMerge"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="Save &amp; Merge"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/ButtonTextColor"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/ButtonTextColor"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

TIA

Comment: please post relevant xml

Comment: It would be very helpful, if you could add the layout xml and screenshots with the normal look.

Comment: create a style template for views, and use same template for all views of that type

Comment: thanks and sorry i didn't put it before, i input the xml code as suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change  `android:gravity="right"` to `android:gravity="center_vertical"` in the linear layout containing the buttons